# Select sub-sub-items of an object

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

being new to linq and Entity Framework this kind of puzzles me:

I created a model (of a tiny section) of my database through Entity Framework, with three tables in two straight-down 1:n relations: **Folder** -> 1:n -> **Contract** -> 1:n -> "Measuring" **Point**

I am looking for a syntax that allows to start on a folder object I iterate with and get back the point (if it exists) to a string I found in a file, comparing by name. I want to completly ignore the middle level contract, just find the point one level lower in all contracts.

I can do this by iterating through each contract like this:

```
foreach (Contract contract in folder.Contract)
{
    Point point = contract.Point.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Pointname == pointname);
    if (point != null)
    { ... other code
    }
}
```

I would like to skip the foreach over contract, but I cannot get the syntax right. I tried these:

```
Point point = folder.contract.SelectMany("???").Point.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Pointname == pointname)
Point point = folder.contract.All(c => c.Point.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Pointname == pointname))
```

Both cannot compile, but there surely is an easy way to do this?

Thanks!

Ralf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need like below code:

```
Point point = folder.Contract
                    .SelectMany(c => c.Point)
                    .SingleOrDefault(p => p.Pointname == pointname)
```

But seems the logic is kind of different with what you show since you check whether `point != null` in each contract.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Change of logic is not a problem: I only need to know if the point is needed at all anywhere.